How to add test case with test steps to azure test suite from Visual studio in c#
I need a way to add test cases with test steps from Visual Studio in C# in Azure test suite. I already tried with REST API, but I am getting an http 400 bad request error.
I tried to add a test case first using work item API but I get 400 bad request.
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
apiVersion = "7.1-preview.3"

public static async Task<string> CreateTestCase(HttpClient client, string azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl, string project, string apiVersion, string testName, List<string> testSteps)
{
    string url = $"{azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version={apiVersion}";

    var testCase = new
                   {
                       op = "add",
                       path = "/fields/System.Title",
                       value = testName
                   };

    var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testCase), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), jsonContent);

 return response;
}


I am able to create a test case with test steps using below code-
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class AzureDevOpsTestCaseCreator
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateTestCase(HttpClient client, string azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl, string project, string apiVersion, string testName, List<string> testSteps)
    {
        string url = $"{azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version={apiVersion}";

        // Create the patch document as a list of operations
        var patchDocument = new List<object>
    {
        new
        {
            op = "add",
            path = "/fields/System.Title",
            value = testName
        }
    };

        // Add test steps
        if (testSteps != null && testSteps.Count > 0)
        {
            var steps = new StringBuilder("<steps>");
            foreach (var step in testSteps)
            {
                steps.AppendFormat("<step id='0' type='Action'><parameterizedString isformatted='true'>{0}</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted='true'></parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted='true'></parameterizedString></step>", step);
            }
            steps.Append("</steps>");

            patchDocument.Add(new
            {
                op = "add",
                path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
                value = steps.ToString()
            });
        }

        var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), jsonContent);

        return response;
    }

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "Omd*******R1ZHE=");

            var response = await CreateTestCase(client, "https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}", "{project_name}", "7.1-preview.3", "Sample Test Case", new List<string> { "Step 1", "Step 2" });

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test case created successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Error creating test case: {response.StatusCode} - {responseContent}");
            }
        }
    }
}

This code gives me expected response.


